# Resolving ambiguous call in template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

A typical function template signature:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
T fn(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init)
{
    T result;
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

The problem is, when I call it like this:

```
std::vector<long> data(1000,1);
fn(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
```

or any other way without explicitly calling

```
fn<std::vector<long>::iterator, long>(data.begin(), data.end(),0);
```

then the type of T is an `int`, and there is a risk of overflow and bad results in `fn`.

So how do I specialize `fn` so that the call to

```
fn(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
```

is unambigous and results in `T` to be set to `Iterator::value_type`? The choice

```
template<Iterator>
typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type fn(Iterator first, Iterator last, typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type init)
{
    //...
}
```

results in an ambiguous call error from g++/clang++.

EDIT:

I see my mistake now and the above code works with @Lightness Races suggestion below. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't replicate the ambiguous call. Can you show us?

Comment: Note: forcing the type `T` to the value_type of the iterator may also result in overflow. Think about `std::accumulate` with `std::vector<char>::iterator`, if we use `init` as '\0' versus `0`...

Comment: @Jarod42: Yeah, you can't get around that by guessing with types. If the function body does something like `std::accumulate` then it should (somehow) ensure that it's got enough room to work with regardless. A specialisation for integral types that performs promotion would probably do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply pass a long?

```
fn(data.begin(), data.end(), 0L);
```

Beyond that you could probably do something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type fn(
   Iterator first,
   Iterator last,
   typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type init
);
```

### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7edb3ed688ef399)

I don't really see how you're at risk of an overflow, though.

Comment: @Jarod42: I suggest to use a better font.

Comment: For the overflow, think about `std::accumulate` with 'big' `int`.

Comment: @Jarod42: I suppose you increase the risk of overflow inside `fn`, but you can't get rid of that

Comment: Right - that will cause overflow.

Comment: @Lightness Races: Yes, this works (the second suggestion). I had stupidly used `Iterator::value_type` instead of `iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` and should have caught my error before the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As:

```
0 is an int
0L is a long
```

You just have to call the method with the correct argument:

- Use directly the correct literal

as:

```
fn(data.begin(), data.end(), 0L);
```

- Or, you may use an intermediate variable

as:

```
long init = 0; // result in 0L

fn(data.begin(), data.end(), init);
```

- or you may cast the value:

as:

```
fn(data.begin(), data.end(), static_cast<long>(0));
```

One way to write `fn` to avoid to call it correctly is

```
template<typename Iterator>
auto fn(Iterator first, Iterator last, typename std::decay<decltype(*first)>::type init)
    -> typename std::decay<decltype(*first)>::type;
```

Comment: Ok but I want to kind of prevent this from happening to myself or someone else. The real problem to me is that I can't specialize to make a proper `fn` now that this one is defined. The second template parameter is completely superfluous - the writer inteneded it always to be a `Iterator::value_type` , and I want to get rid of it.